# Configure MSAL without access to Azure AD administration portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

A customer changed to Azure AD, so we have to update our app accordingly. Unfortunately we don't have either access to the customers's Azure AD administration portal, nor do we have user credentials to test our app. We only know that ...

- All starts here: https://myapplications.microsoft.com
- Browser login consists of (1. dialog) email address, (2. dialog) password, (3. dialog) OTP token entry (OTP sent via SMS). Microsoft Authenticator works as well.
- When through the authentication process, the page with the Azure applications appears. In our app, we'd like to avoid this page showing up, since the app should take over after the OTP token is entered in Microsoft Graph API (= authentication is completed). So authentication webview should close by itself after authentication is finished.

We read a lot about MSAL the last days, but since we have to code blindly (no sample login credentials/OTP available, no Azure AD administration access), it's kind of fishing in the dark.

We used this page as starting point: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc

We use Xcode 13.4.1 with Swift.

By using Safari Web Inspector on the concerned Azure AD application, we populated the required MSAL **constants** as follows:

```
let kClientID = "2793995e-0a7d-40d7-bd35-6968ba142197" // probably not correct, see (a.) below
let kGraphEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/" // not found in Web Inspector data, but most MSAL code uses it
let kAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/" // found in Web Inspector data
let kRedirectUri = "https://myapplications.microsoft.com" // the URL after authentication is complete
let kScopes: [String] = ["User.Read"] // not found in Web Inspector data, but most MSAL code uses it
```

Questions/Problems:

1. https://myapplications.microsoft.com always shows the client_id `2793995e-0a7d-40d7-bd35-6968ba142197`. As far as we understood, every Azure AD application has it's own client_id, hence `2793...` cannot be correct since it's "generic". If the client_id is not correct, can we find the correct one using the concerned Azure AD application Safari Web Inspector data?
2. Above constants seem to work, but when our testers login, the last page showing all Azure AD applications remains open. Some sample MSAL test code from Github however close Microsoft Graph API after credentials were entered. Is this closure of the authentication webview triggered by the server (Azure AD setting) or the client?
3. After testers logged in through the app, then suspended the app (via App Switcher), then opened the app again - the complete Graph API login was required again. Silent login (aquireTokenSilently) didn't work. When using Safari, silent login works however. What could be wrong?
4. Does the Safari Web Inspector data tell us what the product bundle identifer is (which we need for `msauth.$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` as redirect URI)?

**So basically, we'd like to ...**

- avoid the Graph API portal page, which shows up after authentication is done
- remain logged in after app returns from suspended (acquireTokenSilently())
- use Authenticator if installed on the device

We've never worked with Azure AD before.
Any hint about mistakes/misunderstandings would help.
Many thanks!

**----- UPDATE (27.07.2022) -----**

As a reminder ... we neither have access to the Azure AD portal, nor do we have test credentials (username, password, SMS code [OTP]).

After lots of testing and simulating, still no success.

Using Safari, the flow for a regular user looks like this:

1. https://myapplications.microsoft.com
2. The authentication starts with the entry of the organization specific email address.
3. Azure detects this organization, checks the existence of the email address and asks fro the password.
4. Next, Azure either sends an SMS code or triggers the broker (Microsoft Authenticator). It's device configuration specific which one is used.
5. The page with the Azure AD applications opens.

On iOS/macOS (Xcode, our application), the above flow is similar. MSAL debug messages reveal however that no token is sent. `acquireToken()` only completes after the webview is cancelled (MSAL error -50005). It seems that a Web application doesn't require a token ?!

Now ... in our (iOS) app, we only would like to get the token in order to access the Web application with our (iOS) app (using the Bearer inside the URL request).

- How can we get a token for an Web application without redirecting to that page at the same time (which doesn't return a token)?
- Does Azure AD allow access to that Web application using the gained token?

A server side (Azure AD) solution would be an redirect_uri entry in the Authentication section (MY_BUNDLE_ID). But we have to do without.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to target the MyApps app (2793995e-0a7d-40d7-bd35-6968ba142197). You should target your own [Azure AD App registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-ios#register-your-application). For more information please take a look to [MSAL iOS Swift Microsoft Graph API Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-mobile-apple-swift-objc/ios-ms-graph-api/).

Comment: We have no access to the Azure AD portal. We have to implement MSAL access more or less blindly based on user (who have access) web inspector data/feedback provided. We received the clientID now. Access works. However at the end of the Graph API (credentials, SMS code), the Azure apps show up (the acquire token interactively and silently works). Can the client (our app) close (or avoid opening) the page with the Azure apps after authentication is finished? Or is this an Azure AD configuration which the client cannot influence. I read the link(s) you provided. Thanks.

Comment: What page is that? Can you paste the URL? Can you please rephrase the following:  at the end of the Graph API (credentials, SMS code)?

Comment: I can't post the URL of the company concerned - sorry. The UPDATE above (27.07.2022) should clarify the problem.